# Java static methods variables resolved during compile time, loaded during run time?

Tags: java, time, static, compilation

I was reading about the static methods and variables in Java and I found the below two articles on stack overflow.

[Are static methods in Java always resolved at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039229/are-static-methods-in-java-always-resolved-at-compile-time?rq=1)
This says, static methods are resolved at compile time.

[when is static variable loaded in java, runtime or compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343760/when-is-static-variable-loaded-in-java-run) time-or-compile-time

This says, static methods are loaded at compile time.

Shouldn't the compiler load the static variables/methods when it resolves them(say at compile time)?
It's Confusing! Could some one please clarify?

Comment: Well it does. Both the answers says `Compile-Time` only. What are you confused at?

Comment: If you want a method/class be resolved at the time it is really needed you will have to create an Object. But if you still want to have a static like acces, you can go with the sinlgeton pattern, descriped here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: why do people care about compile/run time? it's impl detail.

Answer (score 8):

It seems to me like you are confused about what the terms "resolve" and "load" mean.

Resolving a method/variable means deciding exactly which method/variable is called. For instance methods for example this is done at runtime, which results in the ability of a subclass to override a superclass's methods (polymorphism). Static methods however cannot be overridden and are resolved at compile time.

Loading a variable means actually getting the value into memory. Of course, this can only happen at run time. Specifically, a static variable is loaded when the class itself is loaded.